# Custom style just for width and height?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have some pgfplot graphs in .tikz files and I want to define a custom style to them that only overrides some entries, and uses whats in the .tikz files for the rest.

Example:

In my .tikz file I have

```
\begin{axis}[inTable]
```

In my document I define all [inTable] graphs as:

```
\pgfplotsset{inTable/.style={
width=4.5cm,
height=4.5cm,
scale only axis,
xmin=1,
xmax=511,
xlabel={$q (\mu m^{-1})$},
ymin=0.5,
ymax=1,
ylabel={ylabel}
},
inTable/.belongs to family=/pgfplots/scale,
}
```

But I not all graphs that have `[inTable]` style will necessarily have the same label and x min, x max etc. I want them to have all the same width and height but not necessarily the entries under this. I have tried putting the rest back in the.tikz file eg

```
\begin{axis}[inTable]
scale only axis,
xmin=1,
xmax=511,
xlabel={$q (\mu m^{-1})$},
ymin=0.5,
ymax=1,
ylabel={y label}
```

But it only seems to take whats in the `\pgfplotsset{inTable/.style={`

How can I mix and match? I hope this question makes sense.

Thanks

Comment: @cmhughes my pleasure :) I'll delte ny comments here shortly to tidy up a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've closed the optional argument to the axis environment too early; try

```
\begin{axis}[myTable,scale only axis,..., ylabel={y label}]
```

Here's a complete MWE to play with.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{inTable/.style={
    width=4.5cm,
    height=4.5cm,
    scale only axis,
    xmin=1,
    xmax=511,
    xlabel={$q (\mu m^{-1})$},
    ymin=0.5,
    ymax=1,
    ylabel={ylabel}
    },
    inTable/.belongs to family=/pgfplots/scale,
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[inTable]
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[inTable,
            scale only axis,
            xmin=-20,
            xmax=400,
            xlabel={different},
            ymin=-1.5,
            ymax=10,
        ylabel={y label}]
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly it. One slight problem is that doing it this way is messing with my alignment. But that is for another question.